# Implementing Binary Search Tree To Handle Duplicate Keys in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Below is the code from the example given on the website that I found to help me learn python a little better: [Interactive Python](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/bst.html)

The author explains that:

> One important problem with our implementation of insert is that duplicate keys are not handled properly. As our tree is implemented a duplicate key will create a new node with the same key value in the right subtree of the node having the original key. The result of this is that the node with the new key will never be found during a search. A better way to handle the insertion of a duplicate key is for the value associated with the new key to replace the old value. **We leave fixing this bug as an exercise for you.**"

My question here is, how do I fix this to handle duplicate keys properly? If a key already exists in the tree, then the new payload should replace the old value. The goal would be to not add another node with the same key but I have no idea where to even begin doing so. I am not sure why this is so confusing.

```
class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.root.__iter__()

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,
                                       parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and \
               self.parent.leftChild == self

    def isRightChild(self):
        return self.parent and \
               self.parent.rightChild == self

    def isRoot(self):
        return not self.parent

    def isLeaf(self):
        return not (self.rightChild or self.leftChild)

    def hasAnyChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild or self.leftChild

    def hasBothChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild and self.leftChild

def replaceNodeData(self,key,value,lc,rc):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = value
        self.leftChild = lc
        self.rightChild = rc
        if self.hasLeftChild():
            self.leftChild.parent = self
        if self.hasRightChild():
            self.rightChild.parent = self

    def put(self,key,val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key,val,self.root)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(key,val)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                          parent=currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                          parent=currentNode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_put()` method does the testing and inserting, and it *never tests for equality*. It only tests if the inserted `key` is smaller (inserting the key into the left child), otherwise it'll insert into the right child.

Simply test for equality and replace:

```
def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
    if key == currentNode.key:
        currentNode.value = val

    elif key < currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                      parent=currentNode)
    else:
        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
        else:
            currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                      parent=currentNode)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense now!